# Abstract Resource Model classes

Tags: magento2

Looking at some of the Resource Models in Magento 2, you will find the following class definitions

```
namespace Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel;

abstract class AbstractResource extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity
{
   ...
}

namespace Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel;

class Customer extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\VersionControl\AbstractEntity
{
    ...
}

class Group extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl\AbstractDb
{
    ...
}

class Visitor extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    ...
}
```

As you can see, there are `VersionControl` abstract classes and regular ones.

```
\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity
\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\VersionControl\AbstractEntity
\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl\AbstractDb
```

What is the difference between the two? When you create your own entities, should your Resource Models extend from the `VersionControl` class or the regular one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So just to clarify, in Magento 2:

- `\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\VersionControl\AbstractEntity` extends `\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity`
- `\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl\AbstractDb`
   extends `\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb`

The `VersionControl` classes have the following extra functionalities:

- After loading and after saving an entity, they register a snapshot of entity data `\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl\Snapshot`, for tracking changes. That snapshot is used with the extra `isModified` function to check if entity was modified in the `save` method.
- When saving an entity, a `\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl\RelationComposite` is used to process model's relations saves before and after saving the object.

According to the Magento U fundamental course, when creating your own entities, you should use the `\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity`
 and the `\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb`. The `VersionControl` classes are never mentionned over the course.